# Html5 placeholder Issue on all IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I seem to have a strange problem with HTML5 placeholder.
Im using a drop down menu to show/hide divs and within a div i have few text fields

when i choose one of the options from the drop down to show a div, the div shows up but the placeholders are not in the text fields.

any help would be appreciated.

[The place holder plugin](https://raw.github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim/master/jquery.html5-placeholder-shim.js)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#customertype").change(function() {
            if ($("#customertype option[value='new']").attr('selected')) {
                   $('#newcustomer').show();

            }
            if ($("#customertype option[value='existingcustomer']").attr('selected')) {
                 $('#newcustomer').hide();
                   $('#existingcustomer').show();   
            }
        });
        });
        </script>

   <!--Start New Customer  -->
            <div id="newcustomer" style="display:none;"> 
              <div id="field"> <span id="sprytextfield5">
                <input class="input address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address" id="address" />
                </span> <span id="sprytextfield6">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City" id="city" />
                </span> <span id="sprytextfield7">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="province" placeholder="Enter Province" id="province" />
                </span> <span id="sprytextfield8">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="postalcode" placeholder="Enter Postal Code" id="postalcode" />
                </span> </div>
            </div>
            <!--End New Customer  -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not support placeholders, at least through 9.

https://github.com/madeinstefano/ie-placeholder/blob/master/ie-placeholder.js

Use the following code:

```
    //IE placeholder;
$(function (){
  if (/MSIE 9|MSIE 8|MSIE 7|MSIE 6/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    function resetPlaceholder() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
          .attr('data-placeholder', true)
          .addClass('ie-placeholder');
        if ($(this).is(':password')) {
          var field = $('<input />');
          $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attr) {
            if (attr.name !== 'type') {
              field.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
            }
          });
          field.attr({
            'type': 'text',
            'data-input-password': true,
            'value': $(this).val()
          });
          $(this).replaceWith(field);
        }
      }
    }

    $('[placeholder]').each(function () {
      //ie user refresh don't reset input values workaround
      if ($(this).attr('placeholder') !== '' && $(this).attr('placeholder') === $(this).val()){
        $(this).val('');
      }
      resetPlaceholder.call(this);
    });
    $(document).on('focus', '[placeholder]', function () {
      if ($(this).attr('data-placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('').removeAttr('data-placeholder').removeClass('ie-placeholder');
      }
    }).on('blur', '[placeholder]', function () { resetPlaceholder.call(this); });
    $(document).on('focus', '[data-input-password]', function () {
      var field = $('<input />');
      $.each(this.attributes, function (i, attr) {
        if (['type','data-placeholder','data-input-password','value'].indexOf(attr.name) === -1) {
          field.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
        }
      });
      field.attr('type', 'password').on('focus', function () { this.select(); });
      $(this).replaceWith(field);
      field.trigger('focus');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response, but when the value is added to the field it wont validate my from.

Comment: You can use required attribute to validate the form like this: <input class="input address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Mailing Address" id="address" required/>